# Javascript Logical Operator OR

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I would imagine this is a pretty standard Javascript logical operator example, but I found it funny that a typo made the answer correct. When bored = fasle (false spelt incorrectly), the code executed correctly. Why does "fasle" work? Any input is appreciated.

```js
var tired = false;
var bored = true; 

var nap = function() {
  
  nap = tired || bored; 
  bored = fasle;
  //tired = false;
  if ( nap = true) {
      console.log("they're both true!");
  }
  else ( nap = false); {
      console.log("they're false!");
  }
  
};
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: There's a lot more wrong than just that one operator haha. In the if else statements you are actually setting nap to true and then nap to false. It will print both 'they're true' and 'they're false' I imagine.

Comment: "=" is an assignment operator, nor a comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  @ergonaut I'm currently using Firefox.

Comment: Where are you calling `nap`?

Comment: Nobody seems to have mentioned that assigning nap to another value will also mean the function will not work a second time.

Comment: I neglected to call nap as well. The code worked in Codeacademy. Maybe that's part of the problem. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>`fasle` is evaluated as `undefined`, which then evaluates to false when converted to boolean.</del>

<del>But `false === fasle` evaluate to false, because they have different types.</del>

<del>This will give you an error in strict mode javascript, because undefined variables are not allowed in this case.</del>

I guess your script can run "correctly" **do have something to do with the browser you're using**, which I denied at first. This will just cast an error, when tested on safari and chrome.

BTW, `if ( nap = true)` will always be true and `if ( nap = false)` will always be false. This is because `=` is assign operator while `==` is the equality comparison operator you want. Assign operator will always evaluate to the right operand.

Comment: "fasle is parsed as undefined" --- is it?

Comment: You may try executing `console.log(typeof fasle)`

Comment: I don't see any `typeof` in OP's code. `typeof` allows addressing undefined variables, whereas assignment operator does not. So it **will not** be "parsed as `undefined`", since an exception is thrown.

Comment: @zerkms No, this is not answering OP, its answering you. You may try `console.log(typeof fasle)` to see that fasle is parsed to `undefined`

Comment: Your answer addresses the OP's question. "fasle is parsed as undefined" --- which is not true. You may run OP's code and see that your statement is not correct. http://jsfiddle.net/xuwt2qLb/

Comment: @zerkms Not quite sure what you mean. The answer is for op, the comment is for you.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Check the http://jsfiddle.net/xuwt2qLb/ Your explanation does not correlate with the observed JS behaviour.

Comment: "fasle is evaluated as undefined" --- that's still wrong. `fasle` variable is not evaluated to anything. Just take a second and open jsfiddle before you continue guessing.

Comment: @zerkms That's because you're in strict mode. If you're not, its `undefined`

Comment: "That's because you're in strict mode" --- what makes you thinking so? (since it's **NOT** in a strict mode)